# site map alone good enough for seo with angular 1 app?

Tags: angularjs, kirby

Options for server side rendering the ang apps

1 - pretender.io
Free for up to 250 pages per month
Here is a tut.: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-seo-with-prerender-io

2 - https://github.com/steeve/angular-seo
Open source and free

_escaped_fragment_  idea ie:

localhost/app.html#!/route becomes:

localhost/app.html?_escaped_fragment_=/route

At the server side, phatomjs picks up this translated request and returns a full 
rendered html file for google to crawl.

However has anyone tried running a plain ang app with a site map? I am building an api onto Kirby CMS which has a nice site map functionality... but I don't know if this will be enough for seo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends. Google will try to crawl ajax calls

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more

However this can't be said about other search engines or crawlers.

Sitemap will not help you much, because it does not contain all content of your site. Sitemap is basicaly there to give crawlers map what they should crawl/index.

Comment: So in theory, if the sitemap did contain all the content for the pages it could work...

Comment: No, sitemap is there too show available pages so you make it easier for crawlers to find (if they miss some internal link or page is not internaly linked too, but you want it to be crawled).

Crawlers wont take the content from the sitemap. Imagine that you had something in sitemap and something completely false on actual page. Search engine dont want that.

What are you trying to do? It doesnt make much sense to use angular on static content page (asuming from use of kirby CMS).